# UseEffect hook: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Error: "index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.in Home (created by Context.Consumer)"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/``react-hooks";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Button, Icon, Label } from "semantic-ui-react";

const LikeButton = ({ user, post: { id, likeCount, likes } }) => {
  const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user && likes.find(like => like.username === user.username)) {
      setLiked(true);
    } else {
      setLiked(false);
    }
  }, [likes, user]);

  const [likePost] = useMutation(LIKE_POST_MUTATION, {
    variables: { postId: id },
    update(proxy, result) {
      likes = result.data.likePost.likes;
    }
  });

  const likeButton = user ? (
    liked ? (
      <Button color="red">
        <Icon name="heart" />
      </Button>
    ) : (
      <Button basic color="red">
        <Icon name="heart" />
      </Button>
    )
  ) : (
    <Button as={Link} to="/login" basic color="red">
      <Icon name="heart" />
    </Button>
  );
  return (
    <Button as="div" labelPosition="right" onClick={user ? likePost : null}>
      {likeButton}
      <Label basic color="red" pointing="left">
        {likeCount}
      </Label>
    </Button>
  );
};

const LIKE_POST_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation likePost($postId: ID!) {
    likePost(postId: $postId) {
      id
      likeCount
      likes {
        id
        username
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default LikeButton;
```

it works fine when I unlike a post, like button and count update instantly, but not when i like a post, will have to refresh the page to update the like counts

Comment: can you share a sandbox?

Comment: Code posted does not show any indication that you should get this error. I assume you have an effect that does something asynchronous and sets state after that's finished. However; when asynchronous work has finished your component is unmounted, you can check if your component is mounted before setting state [here](https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted)